# How to update with order in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server, and I have a table that looks like this:

```
i    id   distance
-----------------
41   null    24
49   null    58
38   null    58
48   null    83
95   null    95
44   null    95
23   null    95
```

I want to update id to have a sequence of rows ordered by `distance asc`, then `i asc`

I tried this

```
update mytable
set @id = @id + 1
id = @id
order by distance, i
```

but I am getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near "order"

How to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `ROW_NUMBER` inside a derived table or CTE.

e.g. as below

```
UPDATE T
SET    id = RN
FROM   (SELECT id,
               RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY distance, i)
        FROM   mytable)T
```

Comment: i think it needs where to match records

Comment: @asmgx there is no filtering requirement stated in your question. Are you expecting us to know telepathically that you want some where clause? If you do have that need just add one. This answers the question you asked.